# Меню позиционируется неправильно

Tags: html, css

Если ставлю `text-align: center;` позиционируется справа. Я вообще не понимаю почему так, возможно был такой вопрос, но я не нашел.

```css
.header {
 width: 300px;
 background: #ccc;
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu {
 margin: 5px;
 
}
li {

 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Mr. Robot</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="header">

<div class="menu">
<a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/53818a7b18184753.html"><img src="//images.vfl.ru/ii/1502220287/53818a7b/18184753_m.png" alt="logo" title="logo" border="0"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1 сезон</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2 сезон</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3 сезон</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой эффект создает отступ у `ul` по-умолчанию `padding-left: 40px;`:

```css
.header {
 width: 300px;
 background: #ccc;
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu {
 margin: 5px;
 
}
li {

 display: inline-block;
}


ul {padding: 0;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Mr. Robot</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="header">

<div class="menu">
<a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/53818a7b18184753.html"><img src="//images.vfl.ru/ii/1502220287/53818a7b/18184753_m.png" alt="logo" title="logo" border="0"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1 сезон</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2 сезон</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3 сезон</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, дружище

Answer (score 0):

При просмотре кода-элемента, для `ul` задано `padding-left:40px` 
Попробуй для `ul` задать `padding:0` , лично у меня сработало. 
CSS :

```
ul {
    padding:0;
}
```